# nvcc fatal : Path to libdevice library not specified

Tags: cuda

As mentioned above I'm receiving :

```
nvcc fatal   : Path to libdevice library not specified
```

After searching on the web , I'm sure that this is path issues, but mine is a bit different, and I wasn't able to solve it.

- Somehow my CUDA is not installed in /usr/local, but in  /usr/lib/cuda
- My nvcc path is at : /usr/bin/nvcc
- When I'm trying to install :

  ```
   conda install cudatoolkit=10.0
  ```

  I'm getting a notice that it is already installed , but when I'm doing nvcc --version, I'm seeing
  version 9.1. which is also weird.
- /usr/lib/cuda/bin is in $PATH, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/lib64
- I also find out that I have **nvidia-cuda-toolkit** at /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit, and that libdevice is inside, (i.e /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice)

I'm really clueless, and I'll be happy for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your install location, /usr/lib/cuda is odd, but there is no libdevice.so, that is a shorthand for all the specific cuda libraries, see the man page, man libdevice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will help but I will share my configurations here.
I configured environment variables as follows.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.0/nsight-compute-2020.1.0:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin:$PATH"
export CUDA_HOME="/usr/local/cuda-11.0"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Before adding `CUDA_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I got the same error "nvcc fatal   : Path to libdevice library not specified".

---

> when I'm doing nvcc --version, I'm seeing version 9.1. which is also weird

Is your `/usr/lib/cuda/bin` the first item in `$PATH`?
Bash finds the first program it matches.
Maybe `/usr/local/cuda/bin` is before your `/usr/lib/cuda/bin`?

> I also find out that I have nvidia-cuda-toolkit at /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit, and that libdevice is inside, (i.e /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice)

In my case, `libdevice` is located at `/usr/local/cuda-11.0/nvvm/libdevice` rather than `/usr/local/cuda-11.0/libdevice`.